# i am getting System.TypeException: Invalid date: 30/06/2016

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, date

I am getting:

> System.TypeException: Invalid date: 30/06/2016

exception as I try to enter future dates in my date of birth inputtext. To validate this I have put below code:

```
Date dt=Date.parse(this.bufferdate);        
if (dt > Date.Today()) {
    system.debug('today date'+Date.Today());
    isValid = false;
    isFutureBirthDateError=true;
}
```

Here **bufferdate** is string and value of DateOfBirth.
Please help me with fix. thanks in advance

Comment: date.parse works together with user locale. Probably, you have set locale where separators or orders of numbers are different

Comment: how `bufferdate` value assigned ?

Comment: @Ratan by calendar selection but user has option of editing also as it is inputtext so i am applying validation on that for not entering Future dates

Comment: @kurunve are you talking about the initialization what i have done for the variable in constructor

Answer (score 2):

parse() returns the formatted string depends on the user locale. Check your locale in user record and its date format here [Supported locales](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&language=en)

From your message noticed its not accepting format(dd/mm/yyyy) 30/06/2016, so you may need to change the format of ***bufferdate*** string as per your locale like (mm/dd/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy..) or need to change the locale in user record.